# Visual Studio 2019 Blazor server and webassembly templates missing

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am new to Blazor and I have Visual Studio 2019 16.4.5.  I have installed .Net Core 3.1 SDK.  I am trying to install the **Blazor** **templates**.  I am looking for the Blazor Server app, Blazor WebAssembly app.  I have tried installing the template ([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Template](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates)) via the Package Manager as well as the command prompt but it doesn't seem to be working for because I get the help information.  When I create a new project, I only see **Blazor App** option.

[image]

If you select it, there's not 'Next' button but just 'Create'.

[image]

PM> **dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.2.0-preview1.20073.1**

```
  Restore completed in 497.79 ms for C:\Users\C113850\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.1.101\scratch\restore.csproj.

Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
  -i, --install       Installs a source or a template pack.
  -u, --uninstall     Uninstalls a source or a template pack.
  --nuget-source      Specifies a NuGet source to use during install.
  --type              Filters templates based on available types. Predefined values are "project", "item" or "other".
  --dry-run           Displays a summary of what would happen if the given command line were run if it would result in a template creation.
  --force             Forces content to be generated even if it would change existing files.
  -lang, --language   Filters templates based on language and specifies the language of the template to create.
  --update-check      Check the currently installed template packs for updates.
  --update-apply      Check the currently installed template packs for update, and install the updates.


Templates                                         Short Name               Language          Tags                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console Application                               console                  [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console                       
Class library                                     classlib                 [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library                       
WPF Application                                   wpf                      [C#]              Common/WPF                           
WPF Class library                                 wpflib                   [C#]              Common/WPF                           
WPF Custom Control Library                        wpfcustomcontrollib      [C#]              Common/WPF                           
WPF User Control Library                          wpfusercontrollib        [C#]              Common/WPF                           
Windows Forms (WinForms) Application              winforms                 [C#]              Common/WinForms                      
Windows Forms (WinForms) Class library            winformslib              [C#]              Common/WinForms                      
Worker Service                                    worker                   [C#]              Common/Worker/Web                    
Unit Test Project                                 mstest                   [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest                          
NUnit 3 Test Project                              nunit                    [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit                           
NUnit 3 Test Item                                 nunit-test               [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit                           
xUnit Test Project                                xunit                    [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit                           
Razor Component                                   razorcomponent           [C#]              Web/ASP.NET                          
Razor Page                                        page                     [C#]              Web/ASP.NET                          
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports              [C#]              Web/ASP.NET                          
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart                [C#]              Web/ASP.NET                          
Blazor Server App                                 blazorserver             [C#]              Web/Blazor                           
Blazor WebAssembly App                            blazorwasm               [C#]              Web/Blazor/WebAssembly               
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web                      [C#], F#          Web/Empty                            
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                      [C#], F#          Web/MVC                              
ASP.NET Core Web App                              webapp                   [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages                  
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular                  [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA                          
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react                    [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA                          
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux               [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA                          
Razor Class Library                               razorclasslib            [C#]              Web/Razor/Library/Razor Class Library
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi                   [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI                           
ASP.NET Core gRPC Service                         grpc                     [C#]              Web/gRPC                             
dotnet gitignore file                             gitignore                                  Config                               
global.json file                                  globaljson                                 Config                               
NuGet Config                                      nugetconfig                                Config                               
Dotnet local tool manifest file                   tool-manifest                              Config                               
Web Config                                        webconfig                                  Config                               
Solution File                                     sln                                        Solution                             
Protocol Buffer File                              proto                                      Web/gRPC                             

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new xunit 
    dotnet new --help
```

PM> **dotnet --list-sdks**

```
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.502 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.504 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.507 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.511 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Server Blazor App Template is already installed. You don't have to install it. It is part of Asp.Net Core. But you do have to install the WebAssembly Blazor App Template. Please run this command in the Nuget Package Manager:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.2.0-preview1.20073.1
```

As for the image presented here... don't you see a "Next" button on the right bottom corner? You have to click on the next button, and then select either Server Blazor App or WebAssembly Blazor App...

Hope this helps...

Comment: There is no 'Next' button.  I updated my screenshot to show you. That is the same command I have tried several times but it just gives the output that is in my original post.  It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it form memory. Did you click on the Create button ? After you hit the Create Button, a new window is displayed, which may have two templates on the left-side pane, depending on whether you have installed the WebAssembly template. In any case, you must have the Server Blazor Template, which is the default, and it is automatically installed with Visual Studio and the SDK. On the bottom left corner is a Create Button to end the creation process.

Comment: If something is amissed, I'd suggest that you display your Visual Studio Installer, and choose the Repair option to correct this issue. Good luck....

Comment: Thank you for you help! When I click on the Create button, it just creates the project; there is not another screen.  I'll try repairing it.